# Shortest paths problem with one alteration

Tags: c++, algorithm

Let's say i have a directed graph G(V,E) with positive integer weights at it's edges.What i need to do is find the shortest paths between all vertices using at most K(integer) reverse edges.What i mean by that is:If we are at edge u and there is only a directed edge from v to u we can use it as long as we have not used K reverse edges for this path.This has to be implemented in C++ and give the shortest paths as a result.

I think the main approach to this problem is to conceptually create K+1 copies of the graph where each copy has one reverse edge,copy G_0 has one G_1 two etc.I could then run dijkstra in this graph and find the shortest path from a vertex to all others using as much as K reversed edges.This could be done V times(like johnsons algorithm)to find all possible shortest paths.My question is:how could this be implemented in c++?I excpect we don't have to create this multigraph but i can't see how it can be done otherwise.

Comment: Sounds to me like your question is more one of mathematics than C++. If you can describe the optimal solution mathematically then you can implement it in C++. If you cannot describe it mathematically then you cannot implement it in *any* programming language. So, what is the optimal mathematical solution?

Comment: I think mathematically the solution is to create K+1 graphs and run dijkstra as i said if we only care about time complexity.However,could we somehow keep track of the reverse edges we have used during dijkstra in the original graph using C++ and not really create this huge graph?

Comment: What actually is your question? Is it really putting your approach into C++ or is it whether this approach is sound? Please clarify that and perhaps remove either of the two tags.

Comment: How do you think would K+1 copies help? Any subset of K edges could be reversed, so even for K=1, what would be the G_0, G_1, G_2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know Dijkstra, you know that every vertex has a tentative distance label (initially infinite, except for the source) and you process the vertices in order of that tentative distance by "relaxing" their arcs, that is, updating the tentative distances of their neighbors.

If you allow for a number of arcs to be travelled in the wrong direction, I would go for a dynamic programming approach and have K labels for each vertex with the following semantics: Label 0 is the classic Dijstra label, Label 1 is the minimum distance from the start on a path with at most one reverse arc and so on.

Now, if I am correct, all you got to do is start with infinite labels and labels 0 for the source. Process labels instead of arcs and (again) start with the minimum tentative distance.
In contrast to the original, relaxing reverse arcs is allowed, but will update the K+1 label of the other side of the arc, while relaxing arcs in their normal direction will update the Kth label.